# Android : SurfaceView, why drawing on different thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, surfaceview

`SurfaceView` : As I know, SurfaceView is drawing on different thread ( using `SurfaceHolder.Callback()`).

In one Android Game Project, I see in `SurfaceView` class : they process Physics (location,...) in same class, but when process Graphics (drawing to screen), they use another thread to process. And Android Example `Landern` has used this model too.

Please tell me which advantages of this model ? (means, using another thread to draw to screen rather than drawing on same thread of SurfaceView).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my limited expierience:

If you draw in a seperate thread, you can keep up "background animations" (moving water, gras, burning fires) while you are doing more complex calculations etc. in the "main" thread.

If you do it all in one thread, you basically block all movement while you are drawing and vice versa, every movement/calculation blocks drawing.

Advantages depend on whtt game you want to make. if you make a boardgame without any special animations and effects, you are good to go with one thread I guess.

Comment: Which also mean that it will keep your game responsive to the keyevents which are dispatched on the main thread.